# Prepared Statement query in TextBox using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013, prepared-statement

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and doing this for my personal project.  What I am trying to do is that I tried to use prepared statement in this query however I still get @fname eventhough I typed first name in textbox.  Do you know what is wrong? Sorry, my English is difficult for me but I'm doing my best to explain this.

```
query = "SELECT pkey.keyword AS \"Keyword\", p.title AS \" Title\", p.abstract AS \"Abstract\", p.citation AS \"Citation\", CONCAT_WS(\" \", f.fname, f.lname) AS \"Name\", f.email AS \"Email\" " +
  " FROM paper_keywords pkey" +
  " INNER JOIN papers p ON pkey.id = p.id" +
  " INNER JOIN authorship a ON p.id = a.paperId" +
  " INNER JOIN faculty f ON a.facultyId = f.id WHERE " +
  " f.fname LIKE \"%@fname%\" ";
```

Here is my codes at below:

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(stringConn);
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fnametextBox.Text);
conn.Open();

DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(datatable);

dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
dataGridView1.DataBindings.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wondering why, when you output your query into a messagebox, you still see @fname in the query? If that is so: the query you write with a named sql parameter will stay the same, and will not be substituted by the value you put into the textbox, it is the database that will replace the parameter with your value, so your query will always contain @parameterName, but in the database engine it will use the value of your variable.

Comment: When I run this program, then I typed first name in messagebox, and then I was suppose to see the table in datagrid but I didn't see anything except the column names. Do you think it's something with datagrid?